# Grabbing reCAPTCHA text via BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to grab the text of whatever the captcha is wanting you to solve for. So for example, if the captcha is asking for you to select all the "Cars" then I want to select that value with Beautifulsoup (or another library).

https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api2/demo is the website I'm referencing.

[Captcha Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ASvlJ.png)
So for this one, I want to grab the following line:

```
<strong style="font-size: 22px;">cars</strong>
```

I cannot figure this one out.

This is my current version of code:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(path)
captcha_url = 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api2/demo'
driver.get(captcha_url)

xpath_captch = '//*[@id="recaptcha-demo"]/div/div/iframe'
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
time.sleep(3)
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, xpath_captch).click()
time.sleep(5)
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, "html.parser")
divs = soup.find_all('div')
```

Comment: You're going to have extreme difficulty automating captchas since captchas exist solely to prevent automation.

Comment: I have a process/theory crafting in mind, but if I can't access the text within it then I'm screwed.

Answer (score 0):

Solved by switching Iframes using driver.switch_to.frame(2)

Didn't know these existed.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).